# AS3 Date not serializing to Java Date using BlazeDS

Tags: java, apache-flex, serialization, blazeds, remoteobject

When I pass a Actionscript Value Object that contains a Date variable using BlazeDS it is not getting transferring as a java.util.Date object correctly.  When the setBaseDatefunction gets called on the Java side the baseDate value is NULL.  The weird thing is if I rename the variable on the Java side to `private Date date;` and create a `public void setDate( Date date)` function it works.  The problem is I need to pass 2 different dates so I can't uses this work around.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here are my 2 classes:

AS3

```
package com.shua.flex.valueobjects
{

 [Bindable]
 [RemoteClass(alias='com.shua.valueObjects.myVO')]
 public class myVO
 {

  public var label:String;



  public var endDate:Date;


  public var baseDate:Date;

  public function myVO()
  {
   super();
  } 

 }
}
```

Java:

```
package com.shua.valueObjects;

import java.util.Date;



public class myVO{


 public static String NAME = "myVO";

 private String label;

 private Date endDate;

 private Date baseDate;


 public void setLabel(String label) {
  this.label = label;
 }

 public String getLabel() {
  return label;
 }

 public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
  this.endDate= endDate;
 }

 public Date getEndDate() {
  return this.endDate;
 }

 public void setBaseDate( Date baseDate ){

  this.baseDate = baseDate;
 }

 public Date getBaseDate(){

  return this.baseDate;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the static string in the java object.  I guess the classes need to match exactly for the serialization to automatically work.  So just removing the static name fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sending several Date objects in the same class should not be a problem.

Are you sure you don't have a small error somewhere in the getter or the setter? Do you have both a getter and a setter for the property?

Comment: no the problem isn't the values not getting set correctly.... The issue is the value is coming from the flex as NULL

Comment: to elaborate..... lets say I put a break point in the Java class at the setEndDate funciton... when that gets executed the endDate parameters is NULL... even though it was set in the flex before sending it

Comment: did you already check with a http debugger (Charles for instance) if the date is not null when you send it out? That is before it is received on the server and parsed in BlazeDS.

Comment: thanks for responses.... but yea my dates are going through the http debugger with the correct dates..but i check the object on the server and the cdate = null.... this leads me to believe its something in the setter like you said but I don't see what it could be

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

- Setting the logging level to debug in services-config.xml to gather more information. Described [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=services_logging_3.html).
- Try custom serialization using IExternalizable. Good post [here](http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2008/03/25/flex-air-serialization-lessons-learned/).
- Adding TraceTarget to the application.mxml to get more debug info. [Info](http://www.flashcomguru.com/index.cfm/2009/8/21/tracetarget-flex).
- Since the package names don't match, did you register the class alias or reference the object in the application.mxml? [Here](http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2008/03/25/flex-air-serialization-lessons-learned/#comment-42266).